How to see if two lists of nonhashable objects are the same in any order in python?
I have two lists of nonhashable objects of the class, let's say, Car with many attributes for each object. An operator overloader for == is defined for the class such that car1==car2 if all the attributes are the same (so you can compare object to object of this class). I have two lists which have no particular order to them (so it's not as simple as just going element by element and comparing if each object is equal). I essentially want to go through each list and see if they have the same elements in any order. Moreover, the loops can have duplicates so they can be different sizes. For instance, list2 of objects could have 3 duplicates, and as long as that object is in list1 then this is still fine.  I could do this in O(n^2) using two for loops, but is there a better and more pythonic way to handle this?

Do you have the operation < or > defined?

Are you able to convert the objects into an equivalent representation that is hashable or ordered? E.g., a tuple of the relevant attributes?

@patoba __ or __ is not defined, but could be. Ideally looking for a solution without using __ or __.

@Brian61354270 I wouldn't know of a way off hand to "order" them as not sure what would be a good criterion to order by. As for converting to a tuple, I would need to not make a tuple of all the objects, but make a tuple of all the attributes, correct? And this is assuming the attributes in the tuple are hashable correct? I don't want to make the assumption the attributes are all hashable.

The standard solution would be what Brian mentioned. Your type may not be orderable/hashable, but it can almost certainly be mapped onto one that is. If you share the specifics of your Car class, one of us could show you how to do so. If it's a @dataclass or attrs class, you can probably do it in a reasonably automated way too.

If you can't order the list, then I don't think there's a way without two loops. every(c1 in car2 for c1 in car1) and every(c2 in car1 for c2 in car1). Note that if the first call fails, it won't do the second one, because of short-circuiting.

@nocomment I think that's equivalent for them: "list2 of objects could have 3 duplicates, and as long as that object is in list1 then this is still fine."

If not, the solution is to sort the two lists, then just compare them.

@Barmar Ah, right. I guess my brain shuts down in the middle of such long paragraphs.

@Barmar this is what I just ended up doing. they're not long lists so it's not a big computational burden. Thanks
